# OpenCV - Feature Matching vs Optical Flow

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am interested in making a motion tracking app using OpenCV, and there has been a wealth of information available online. However, I am a tad confused between feature matching and tracking features using a sparse optical flow algorithm such as Lucas-Kanade. With that in mind, I have the following questions:

- What is the main difference between the two (feature matching and optical flow) if I have specified a region of pixels to track? I'm not interested in tracking in real time, if that helps clear up any assumptions.
- In addition, since I'm not doing real time tracking, is it a better idea to use dense optical flow (Farneback) to keep track of the pixels in my specified region of interest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would like to add a few thoughts about that theme since I found this a very interesting question too.
As said before **Feature Matching** is a technique that is based on:

- A feature **detection** step which returns a set of so called feature points. These feature points are located at positions with salient image structures, e.g. edge-like structures when you are using FAST or blob like structures if you are using SIFT or SURF.
- The second step is the **matching**. The association of feature points extracted from two different images. The matching is based on local visual descriptors, e.g. histogram of gradients or binary patterns, that are locally extracted around the feature positions. The descriptor is a feature vector and associated feature point pairs are pairs a minimal feature vector distances.

Most feature matching methods are *scale* and *rotation* *invariant* and are *robust for changes in illuminations* (e.g caused by shadow or different contrast). Thus these methods can be applied to **image sequences** but are **more often** used to **align image pairs** captured from different views or with different devices.The disadvantage of Feature Matching methods is the difficulty of defining where the feature matches are spawn and that the feature pair (which in a image sequence are motion vectors) are in general very **sparse**. In addition the subpixel accuracy of matching approaches are very limited as most detector are fine-graded to integer positions.

From my experience the **main advantage** of feature matching approaches is that they can compute very **large motions/ displacements**.

OpenCV offers some feature matching methods but there are a lot of more recent, faster and more accurate approaches available online e.g.:

- [DeepMatching](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/src/deepmatching/) which relies on deep learning and are often used to initialize optical flow methods to help them deal with long-range motions.
- [Stereoscann](http://www.cvlibs.net/software/libviso/) which is a very fast approach at its origin proposed for visual odometry.

**Optical flow** methods in contrast rely on the minimization of the brightness constancy and additional constrain e.g. smoothness etc. Thus they derive motion vector based on spatial and temporal image gradients of a sequence of consecutive frames. Thus they are more suited **image sequences**  rather than image pairs that are captured from very different view points. The **main challenges** in the estimation of motion with optical flow vectors  are **large motions**, **occlusion**, **strong illumination changes** and **changes of the appearance of the objects** and mostly the **low runtime**. However optical flow methods can be *highly accurate* and compute **dense motion fields** which respect to shared motion boundaries of the objects in a scene.

However, the accuracy of different optical flow methods is very different. **Local** methods such as the PLK (Lucas Kanade) are in general less accurate but allow to compute pre selected motion vectors only and can thus be very fast. (In the recent years we have done some research to improve the accuracy of the local approach, see [here](https://github.com/tsenst/RLOFLib) for further information).

The main **OpenCV** trunk offers global approaches such as the Farnback. But this is a quite outdated approach. Try the **OpenCV contrib** trunk which more recent methods. But to get an good overview of the most recent methods take a look at the public optical flow benchmarks. Here you will find code and implementations as well e.g.:

- [MPI-Sintel](http://sintel.is.tue.mpg.de/results) optical flow benchmark
- [KITTI 2012](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_stereo_flow.php?benchmark=flow) optical flow benchmark. Both offer links e.g. to git's or source code for some newer methods. Such as [FlowFields](https://www.dfki.de/web/research/publications?pubid=7987).

But from my point of view I would not on an early stage reject a specific approach matching or optical flow. Try as much as possible available online implementations and see what is the best for your application.

Comment: **"_Thus they are more suited image sequences rather than image pairs that are captured from very different view points._"** That's very interesting, most of my tests are coming from video stock footage, and the results I am getting using OpenCV's implementation of LK more than suits our requirements (_so far..._). Thank you. That was very helpful!

Comment: *"Thus they are more suited image sequences..."* -- to confirm, you meant "They are more suited when the camera is fixed/stationary and the things are moving", correct?

Answer (score 9):

Feature matching uses the feature descriptors to match features with one another (usually) using a nearest neighbor search in the feature descriptor space. The basic idea is you have descriptor vectors, and the same feature in two images should be near each other in the descriptor space, so you just match that way.

Optical flow algorithms do not look at a descriptor space, and instead, looks at pixel patches around features and tries to match those patches instead. If you're familiar with dense optical flow, sparse optical flow just does dense optical flow but on small patches of the image around feature points. Thus optical flow assumes brightness constancy, that is, that pixel brightness doesn't change between frames. Also, since you're looking around neighboring pixels, you need to make the assumption that neighboring points to your features move similarly to your feature. Finally, since it's using a dense flow algorithm on small patches, the points where they move cannot be very far in the image from the original feature location. If they are, then the pyramid-resolution approach is recommended, where you scale down the image before you do this so that what once was a 16 pixel translation is now a 2 pixel translation, and then you can scale up with the found transformation as your prior.

So feature matching algorithms are all-in-all far better when it comes to using templates where the scale is not exactly the same, or if there's a perspective difference in the image and template, or if the transformations are large. However, your matches are only as good as your feature detector is exact. On optical flow algorithms, as long as it's looking in the right spot, the transformations can be really, really precise. They're both computationally expensive a bit; optical flow algorithms being an iterative approach makes them expensive (and although you'd think the pyramid approach can eat up more costs by running on more images, it can actually make it faster in some cases to reach the desired accuracy), and nearest neighbor searches are also expensive. Optical flow algorithms OTOH can work really well when the transformations are small, but if anything in your scene messes with your lighting or you get some incorrect pixels (like say, even minor occlusion) can really throw it off.

Which one to use definitely depends on the project. For a project I worked on with satellite imagery, I used dense optical flow because the images of desert terrain I was working with did not have precise enough features (in location) and different feature descriptors happen to look relatively similar so searching that feature space wasn't giving tons of great matches. In this case, optical flow was the better method. However, if you were doing image alignment on satellite imagery of a city where buildings can occlude parts of the scene, there are a lot of features that will stay matched and give a better result.

The [OpenCV Lucas-Kanade tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html) doesn't give a whole lot of insight but should get your code moving in the right direction with the above in mind.

Comment: Wow, what a great post! That was rich in information. Thank you, Alexander. Based on your post, will applying a shape mask for your ROI improve the results of dense optical flow, such as 'shape' of the results returned by something like `cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback`?

Comment: @JDBones I'm afraid I don't follow; the optical flow methods in OpenCV do not allow the inclusion of a mask. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. What I meant is that masking the region of pixels of my ROI with black, thus only retaining the subimage within the bounds of my mask points. So long as the dimensions of `imgPrev` and `imgCur` are the same, this shouldn't fail some assertion within my dense optical flow call.

Comment: @JDBones Sorry, still not following. Do you mean that you have a non-rectangular ROI and thus you want to black out some of the pixels within the rectangular ROI to make up for it? If so, no---dense optical flow will assume those black pixels will also be in the next image, and sparse algorithms will include those as features of the image (the edges for instance).

Comment: For sparse algorithms, you could remove feature points that are outside a non-rectangular ROI. For dense algorithms, the C++ interface does allow for a mask in `findTransformECC()`, see the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga7ded46f9a55c0364c92ccd2019d43e3a).

Answer (score 2):

key-point matching = sparse optical flow

KLT tracking is a good example of sparse flow, see the demo LKDemo.cpp (it had some python wrapper example too, cant remember it now).

for a dense example, see samples/python/opt_flow.py, using Farnebäcks method.

You are right in being confused... The entire world is confused about this terribly simple topic. Alot of the reason is because people believe Lucas-Kanade to be sparse flow (due to a terribly badly named and commented example in openCV: LKdemo which should be called KLTDemo).